# Swift: how to listen scrollViewDidScroll from another class

Tags: swift, delegates, closures

I have two classes: `Foo` & `Bar`:

```
// Foo

protocol FooDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(offset: CGFloat)
}

class Foo: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var delegate: FooDelegate?         

    // code truncated for brevity

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        delegate?.scrollViewDidScroll(offset: scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    }

}


// Bar

class Bar: UIViewController, FooDelegate {

    // code truncated for brevity

    func scrollViewDidScroll(offset: CGFloat) {
        print(offset)
    }

}
```

I need to listen for `Foo`'s `scrollViewDidScroll` event in `Bar`. Is it a correct approach to use `delegates` in this situation? Or there is a better way? I came from the Javascript world where I would use a `callback` to invoke my function on each `scrollViewDidScroll` event. Are `callbacks` used in `Swift` in the same manner as in the Javascript?

Comment: You could use your own delegate as you are here. You could set your scrollView's delegate to Bar directly. You could also create a property for a closure on Foo and let Bar set that. They are all valid approaches.

Comment: Maybe you can show an example for 1. "You could set your scrollView's delegate to Bar directly." and 2. "You could also create a property for a closure on Foo and let Bar set that"

Comment: Couple examples in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I stated, what you have setup is totally valid as a solution to abstract that information out. But lets look at the other two possibilities I might use.

Starting with setting the delegate directly. If the only thing happening in `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` is calling your delegate and that is the only UIScrollViewDelegate method you're working with, then you could merely set the delegate directly.

```
class Bar: UIViewController, FooDelegate {

    let foo = Foo()
    func setup() {
        foo.scrollView.delegate = self
    }

}
```

If your objects are pretty coupled already, this is an ok approach. Though I see in your example you're using a UICollectionView so its likely this isn't your only delegate method in use. So lets look at a closure.

```
class Foo: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var scrollOffSetClosure: ((offset: CGFloat) -> Void)?

    // code truncated for brevity

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollOffSetClosure(offset: scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    }

}

class Bar: UIViewController, FooDelegate {

    func presentFoo() {
        let foo = Foo()
        foo.scrollOffSetClosure = { offset in
            // do something with offset
        }

        present(foo, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

You could set the property anytime but I just used the example of presenting the next viewController and setting the closure before presentation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and examples!

Comment: Glad it was helpful  Happy Coding!